# How to decide on the appropriate measure of centrality for a given set of data

Tags: mean, outliers, skewness, median

I am trying to find the best centrality of a set of 10 points generated randomly. Each time I try to generate the various data points using `x=rnorm(10)`, I get a different histogram each time. Some times it is left skewed and mean is less and some times right and mean is greater than median.

I would like to know the centrality that best summarizes a set of 10 points distributed according to a normal random variables as `rnorm()` will be generating different points each time.

Should I always go with median for skewed distribution ignoring the mean?

Comment: As your data points are by construction samples from a normal distribution, there is no reason not to use a mean. The objection that means differ in small samples is no objection at all as the same objection would apply to (e.g) medians too. It should be no surprise either that small samples from any symmetric distribution may appear to be skew. Although in this case people can guess easily what `rnorm()` does citing syntax should in general be avoided unless it's central to your problem and you also cite the software.

Comment: The main value of this exercise may be to show how small --indeed very small --  samples can vary so much.

Comment: @NickCox Sounds like that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "best summarizes" might mean?  In your example, since you always generate data from a Normal$(10,1)$ distribution, the very best estimator of central tendency is the constant value $10$. Presumably you're interested in more general cases, but how general? Will you assume the numbers come from some distribution that is Normal?  Will you assume you know its variance or not?  Will its mean be known to lie within some given set?  Or will you broaden even these assumptions to encompass non-Normal distributions?

Comment: @Kodiologist Thanks, but as in whuber's comment it seems that the real question was one not quite asked.